# Pass input id to url in jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to pass the id of the input to the url of a remote datasource.

I have got it working via a hack but I feel I am doing things twice, is there any way I can get the input id without using the keypress function?

I need the input id passed to the url because there is some logic in the PHP file depending on which input is being used.

the html

```
<input id="input1" class="selector" type="text">
```

the js

```
    $(".selector").keypress(function() {
        var param2id = $(this).attr('id'); // this id needs to pass to the url


        $(".selector").autocomplete({
            minLength: 1,
            max: 10,
            source: "source.php?param2=" + param2id + "", // passed from the keypress
            focus: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).val(ui.item.value);
                return false;
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).val(ui.item.value);
                return false;
            }
        });


    });
```

Comment: do You want a source from a php file by sending the id?

Comment: the id name is really just a category within a mysql table eg: input1 would select red, input2 would select white from the colour column. jquery ui already has a default way of passing the search term via a get field called 'term', I just need a second parameter passed down the url.

Comment: In the autocomplete function you can also use `$(this).attr(...)`.

Comment: @Mouser thanks for your response, where do you place it in the code?, I did look at this but I couldn't make it work, it would really make my day if that would work.

Comment: @Jason I've posted a code, solution was a bit more difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually a bit more complex, since autocomplete won't reference the element it's set on. So you can wrap them via an each function, so you don't have to use `keypress`. This will set the reference only once.

```js
$('.selector').each(function(i, el) {
    param2id = $(el).attr("id");
    $(el).autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        max: 10,
        source: "source.php?param2=" + param2id + "",
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.value);
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.value);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input class="selector" id="input1">
```